# BindingList Detect Changing (filter)

Tags: c#, datagridview, filtering, auto-update, bindinglist

I have class with property, i'm using `INotifyPropertyChanged` for detecting update.

```
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

  string _lastname;
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string p)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
  }

  public string LastName { get { return _lastName; } set { _lastName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("LastName"); } }

  public Employee(string lastName)
  {
    LastName = lastName;
  }

}
```

I bind it to DataGriView and it's work fine, LastName auto update, if changing.
But if i trying to do this:

```
BindingList<Employee> employees = new BindingList<Employee>();
private void BindMain()
{
   employees.Add(new Employee("Mike"));
   employees.Add(new Employee("Mike"));
   employees.Add(new Employee("Joo"));
   employees.Add(new Employee("Kate"));

   dataGridView.DataSource = employees; // That's working fine, all data auto update
}

private void BindFiltered()
{
  List<Employee> filtered = employees.Where(r=>r.LastName.Equals("Mike").ToList()); //
  BindingList<Employee> filteredEmployee = new BindingList<Employee>(filtered);
  dataGridView.DataSource = filteredEmployee; //not working auto update
  // Trying also with BindingSource
  BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
  bs.DataSource = employees.Where(r=>r.LastName.Equals("Mike"));
  dataGridView.DataSource = bs;

}
```

..auto update does not work.

Comment: _But if i trying to do this:_ Please do continue the post until it actaully asks a question!

Comment: Sorry, in the second case auto update not working.

Comment: Maybe [BindingListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091143/datagridview-not-updating-when-bound-bindinglist-is-changed) works better for you?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it's not working too ..

Comment: The data is updated, if I will do something (for example, change the selected cell)

Comment: That sounds a lot as if you need to somehow trigger some edit to complete/commit. Are there edits involved? Can you find a spot where a EndEdit might help? How is the change supposed to be activated?

Comment: TaW, thanks for the help ! The reason was that the data was updated in another thread, but during the update DataGrid they had not time to update.